# Melhor maneira de usar Criptografia AES

Tags: php, criptografia, hash

Galera, digamos que eu esteja trabalhando em um sistema em que a chave de criptografia é derivada da senha do usuário (algo como o que o KeePass faz), nesse caso eu tenho três dúvidas:

Qual algorítimo utilizar para derivar a chave? De maneira que ela seja o mais distante o possível da senha e que sempre tenha 256 BIT?

E se caso o usuário redefina a senha dele, o que aconteceria com a chave e com os dados já criptografados? lembrando que todos os dados (dele, informações dos clientes, etc...) serão criptografados de maneira que apenas ele tenha acesso às informações originais ao logar no sistema, nesse sentido nem eu (programador) conseguiria recuperar os dados mesmo que quisesse. Outro detalhe é que esse é um sistema que apenas um usuário acessará, mas terá um volume considerável de dados.

E por ultimo, isso é viável? ou seria melhor eu gerar uma Chave "Mestra" que apenas ele teria que armazenar e então informaria junto da senha, toda vez que logasse em um novo dispositivo? Assim como o que o 1Password faz.

PS: com armazenar quero dizer lembrar/guardar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Qual algorítimo utilizar para derivar a chave? De maneira que ela seja o mais distante o possível da senha e que sempre tenha 256 BIT?

O "melhor" é o Argon2i que está disponível no PHP 7.2 (ou via PECL). Mas, como talvez não tenha o LibSodium, tem outras opções.

Você tem o `hash_pbkdf2` disponível no PHP 5.5, ele usa o PBKDF2. Resumidamente, o PBKDF2 faz um *loop* de HMAC, usando um salt e a entrada de usuário, isso faz a derivação de chave. Ele tem um comprimento personalizável, existe um máximo baseado no algoritmo utilizado, salvo engano, assim como o HKDF (que é o `hash_hkdf`).

O fato de existir a um número de iterações atrasa a descoberta da senha, uma vez que ataques de dicionário (e afins) serão mais lento conforme maior for a dificuldade e também "mais distante" da entrada original. Por padrão o PBKDF2 usa SHA-1, mas isso não é recomendado, utilize algoritmos de hashing mais recentes e confiáveis (SHA-3,  SHA-2 ou BLAKE).

```
string hash_pbkdf2 ( string $algo , string $password , string $salt , int $iterations [, int $length = 0 [, bool $raw_output = false ]] )
```

Exemplo:

```
$sal = random_bytes(16); // 128-Bits de salt
$iteracoes = 250000; // 250 000 iterações
$tamanho = 256;

if($sal !== false){
    $hash = hash_pbkdf2(
        "sha384", // SHA-2 de 384 bits
        $senha, // Sua senha
        $sal,
        $iteracoes,
        $tamanho,
        true);
}
```

Porém, a melhor opção fica no LibSodium, que é o `sodium_crypto_pwhash`, ele utiliza o algoritmo que foi o vencedor do [PHC](https://password-hashing.net/), o Argon2i. Seu uso é similar ao PBKDF2, com a diferença que temos mais opções do que apenas escolher a quantidade de  "iterações".

```
string sodium_crypto_pwhash(int $output_length, string $password, string $salt, int $opslimit, int $memlimit)
```

Exemplo:

```
$sal = random_bytes(SODIUM_CRYPTO_PWHASH_SALTBYTES);
$tamanho = 256;
$limiteOperacoes = 32; // 8 vezes maior que o padrão
$limiteMemoria = 1<<27; // 4 vezes maior que o padrão

if($sal !== false){
    $hash = sodium_crypto_pwhash(
        $tamanho,
        $senha, // Sua senha
        $sal,
        $limiteOperacoes,
        $limiteMemoria
    );
}
```

O valor de `opslimit`e o `memlimit` padrão pode ser obtido por `SODIUM_CRYPTO_PWHASH_OPSLIMIT_INTERACTIVE` e `SODIUM_CRYPTO_PWHASH_MEMLIMIT_INTERACTIVE`, eles são bases seguras, quanto maior que isto supostamente melhor. O primeiro valor exigirá maior poder de CPU, maior quantidade de ciclos. Já o segundo exigirá maior quantidade de memoria.

Porém, utilizar senhas fracas (alá 123456789) não terá derivação que salve.

*Você também pode usar o SCrypt, mas nunca utilizei isto no PHP e não há planos de ser suportado nativamente no PHP.*

Uma vez que a senhas são sensiveis, elas não devem ficar na memoria por muito tempo, portanto após a derivação utilize:

```
sodium_memzero($senha);
```

> E se caso o usuário redefina a senha dele, o que aconteceria com a chave e com os dados já criptografados?

Simples. Basta que "descriptografe" com a senha antiga e então criptografe com o resultado da derivação da nova senha.

Se o usuário não souber a senha atual, que atualmente é usada, já era. É melhor que ele perca o acesso aos dados do que qualquer um ter. ;)

> E por ultimo, isso é viável? ou seria melhor eu gerar uma Chave "Mestra" que apenas ele teria que armazenar e então informaria toda vez que logasse em um novo dispositivo? Assim como o que o 1Password faz.

Não sei como o 1Password funciona, mas duvido muito que ele utilize apenas uma "Chave Mestra". Possivelmente ele tem um senha (escolhida pelo usuário) e uma chave, em conjunto podem ser utilizadas para derivar uma nova chave ou cada um (a senha e a chave) sejam utilizadas para um propósito diferente, ou ainda a senha sirva para descriptografar a própria chave. O que acredito (isso é totalmente um chute) é que cada um tem um próposito, a sua senha (e sua derivação) serve para encriptar/decriptar, enquanto que a chave mestra serve para autenticação, para provar  que você é quem diz ser.

*São propósitos diferentes, mas isso é só um chute. Talvez o 1Password tenha alguma informação publica de como funciona, mas não achei.*

Comment: Sua explicação foi muito esclarecedora, nesse caso vou utilizar a derivação  da senha mesmo, porém irei "obrigar" o usuário a criar uma senha mais segura, como ele mesmo exigiu que o sistema fosse "seguro" não tem problema eu obriga-lo a criar uma senha mais elaborada.

Comment: Realmente esqueci de mencionar que ele usa Master Key + Password do usuário. Eles explicam o fluxo básico, mas também não achei documentação especifica. Como tenho conta nele sei que ele gera essa Master Key apenas uma vez e deixa por minha conta a "segurança" dela. O login é efetuado informando ambos, Password e Master Key. Tem uma parte que menciona que a Master Key é a "evolução" (ou algo do tipo) da autenticação em 2 fatores, então eu diria que seu chute deve estar correto mesmo.

Comment: Só complementar pra quem tiver interesse no 1Password, achei esse documente deles, realmente muito completo: https://1password.com/files/1Password%20for%20Teams%20White%20Paper.pdf